# SwiftUI: Run Code on the view when the CLAuthorizationStatus changes

Tags: swiftui

I want to run some code (fetching records to populate a List) when permission is granted for location access.

Here is my Location Manager:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var locationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus?    

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        locationStatus = status
        print("This is the Model")
        print(status == .authorizedWhenInUse)
        
    }
    
        
}
```

And here is my view:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct HorizontalPerformanceListView: View {
    
    
    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()
                
    var performanceSet: PerformanceSet
                
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack (spacing: 10) {
                //iterate over a fetched records
            }
            .onReceive(locationManager.$locationStatus) { _ in self.runCode() }
                            
    }
    
    func runCode(){
        print("This is the View")
        print(locationManager.locationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse)
        if(locationManager.locationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse){
            print("run code here")
        }
    }
            
}
```

When the user prompted for location permission and specifies "allow while using app", I'd expect the "RunCode" func to run and for locationManager.locationStatus to be set to .authorizedWhenInUse.

The console prints instead:

```
This is the View
false
This is the Model
true
This is the View
false
This is the Model
true
```

The locationStatus is clearly changing in the model when permission is granted but my view still thinks access isn't there.

Clearly I am doing something wrong (I am somewhat new to SwiftUI/Combine) - I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`. `@StateObject` is for data your view owns (i.e. instantiates), `@ObservedObject` is for data not owned by your view (i.e. passed in as an argument to your view).

Additionally, the publisher is an `objectWillChange` notification (i.e. it hasn't changed yet). Try using an `asyncAfter` delay to observe it correctly.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct HorizontalPerformanceListView: View {
    
    
    @StateObject var locationManager: LocationManager = LocationManager()
                
    var performanceSet: PerformanceSet
                
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack (spacing: 10) {
                //iterate over a fetched records
            }
            .onReceive(locationManager.$locationStatus) { _ in self.runCode() }
                            
    }
    
    func runCode(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            print("This is the View")
            print(locationManager.locationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse)
            if(locationManager.locationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse){
                print("run code here")
            }
        }
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @mrbenhill updated with info about async after. See also https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/manually-publishing-observableobject-changes